# Building Acropolis (District)

Tags: civilization-6

I have question about this situation... I want to play Acropolis (Culture District - Greeks)

1. Why I am getting +2 Culture Bonus on Top-Right Hex -> 1 for city is clear and the other for adjacent district is really not, as there is no adjacent district...I ahve only Campus, which is really far from there
2. Why I cannot build the Acropolis on the Hex on right of Sparta?
   [image]

Thanks for any answers/clarifications..

Answer (score 1):

The City Centre itself is considered a district. Hence, it provides these two bonuses. The explanation of the Acropolis lists:

> +1 Culture bonus for each adjacent district and an additional +1 Culture bonus for adjacent City Center.[...]

Comment: Ah ok, that make sense then. I didn't know that. Thank you. Also I found that i can be only build on hills...that is the reason why cannot be build on right HEX.

Comment: Which is unique to the Acropolis, a normal culture district doesn't have a hills requirement